# Loading data from a file to an array in c

Tags: c, arrays, file, load, save

I want to load an array from a file that I previously saved.  I ran the code below, but for some reason, when I loaded the array, the array length that I loaded was not the same as the length of the array that I had saved.  How would I change the length for my load a file code so that it would work for any array length?

```
intarr_t* intarr_load_binary( const char* filename )
{
    unsigned int len = 0;
    FILE *f = fopen (filename, "rb");
    fscanf (f, "%d", len);
    intarr_t* newia = malloc (sizeof(intarr_t));
    assert (newia);
    newia->data = malloc (len*sizeof(int));
    assert(newia->data);
    newia->len = len;
    if (f != NULL)
    {
        while (!feof(f))
        {
            fscanf (f, "%d", newia->data);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    fclose (f);
    return newia;
}
```

The struct that I used for the save/load is here:

```
typedef struct {
  int* data;
  unsigned int len;
} intarr_t;
```

The code that I used to save the file is here:

```
int intarr_save_binary( intarr_t* ia, const char* filename )
{
    unsigned int len = ia->len;
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen (filename, "wb");
    if (fwrite (ia->data, sizeof(int), len, f) == len)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
    fclose (f);
}
```

Comment: Also, you don't need to return `intarr_t*` from `intarr_load_binary`. You can just return `intarr_t`.

Comment: Anyway, you are testing for errors far too sparingly. And your `intarr_save_binary` returns before it gets a chance to close the file.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I just want to clarify. What do you mean by save len?

Comment: @user3121023 would i need to change the length of the array in my load function after adding fread? If so, what should i change it to? Right now i have it set as 0.

Comment: To load the number of record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
the code is writing no length (len) value as the first data item to the file
yet the code is reading a length (len) value 
as if it were the first data item in the file.

this code is full of errors and oversights:

int intarr_save_binary( intarr_t* ia, const char* filename )
{
    unsigned int len = ia->len;
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen (filename, "wb");
    if (fwrite (ia->data, sizeof(int), len, f) == len)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
    fclose (f);
}

suggest using code similar to this:

int intarr_save_binary( intarr_t* ia, const char* filename )
{
    int returnValue = 0;
    unsigned int len = ia->len;
    FILE *f;

    if( NULL == (f = fopen (filename, "wb") )
    {
        perror( "fopen failed" );
        returnValue = 1;
    }

    else if ( fwrite ( &len, sizeof(int), 1, f) == 1 )
    { // then write of length successful

        if (fwrite (ia->data, sizeof(int), len, f) == len)
        {
            returnValue = 0; // indicate success
        }

        else
        { // else, write of data failed
            returnValue = 3;
        }
    }
    else
    { // else, failed to write len value to file
        returnValue = 4;
    }

    fclose( f ); // cleanup (writes last buffer to file)
    return( returnValue );
} // end function: intarr_save_binary
```

Comment: you might want to re-arrange the code slightly so that all errors are handled immediately after a I/O call, just to make the code flow better

Answer (score 0):

```
this code needs some work.  
for instance because assert should not enabled in production code
and error conditions not being checked
and cleanup not being properly performed

if the program is ok to continue after an I/O error 
by always returning NULL
then you could change the following, 
to return NULL rather than exiting the program

intarr_t* intarr_load_binary( const char* filename )
{
    unsigned int len = 0;
    FILE *f = fopen (filename, "rb");
    fscanf (f, "%d", len);
    intarr_t* newia = malloc (sizeof(intarr_t));
    assert (newia);
    newia->data = malloc (len*sizeof(int));
    assert(newia->data);
    newia->len = len;
    if (f != NULL)
    {
        while (!feof(f))
        {
            fscanf (f, "%d", newia->data);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    fclose (f);
    return newia;
}

suggest:

intarr_t* intarr_load_binary( const char* filename )
{
    unsigned int len = 0;
    FILE *f = NULL;
    intarr_t* newia = NULL;

    if( NULL == fopen (filename, "rb") )
    { // then, fopen failed
        perror( "fopen failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    } // end if

    // implied else, fopen successful

    if( NULL == (newia = malloc (sizeof(intarr_t)) )
    { // then malloc failed
        perror( "malloc failed" );
        fclose(f);
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    } // end if

    // implied else, malloc successful

    if( (fread (&len, sizeof(int), 1, f) != 1 ) ) 
    { // then fread failed
        perror( "fread failed" );
        fclose(f);
        free( newia );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    } // end if

    // implied else, fread for len successful

    newis->len = len;

    if( NULL == (newia->data = malloc (len*sizeof(int)) ) )
    { // then malloc failed
        perror( "malloc failed" );
        fclose(f);
        free( newia );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    } // end if

    // implied else, malloc successful

    if( fread( newia->data, sizeof(int), len, f ) != len )
    { // then, fread failed
        perror( "fread failed" );
        fclose(f);
        free(newia->data)l
        free(newia);
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    } // end if

    // implied else, fread successful

    fclose (f);
    return newia;
}  // end function: intarr_load_binary
```